# How do I read phonebook number labels?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, abperson

I know how to get the phone number from an `ABRecordRef`, but what I want now is to also get the type of the number, i.e. its label as a string:

```
const CFStringRef kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel;
const CFStringRef kABPersonPhoneMainLabel;
const CFStringRef kABPersonPhoneHomeFAXLabel;
const CFStringRef kABPersonPhoneWorkFAXLabel;
const CFStringRef kABPersonPhonePagerLabel;
```

Here is how I get the numbers:

```
//get all phone numbers                   
NSArray *phoneNumbersArray = (NSArray*)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phoneNumberProperty);
NSInteger numbersCounter = 0;
for(numbersCounter = 0; numbersCounter < [phoneNumbersArray count]; numbersCounter++)
{
     NSString currentPhoneNumber = [phoneNumbersArray objectAtIndex:indexPhoneNumber];

      // here i would like to read the type of phone number 
      // NSLog(@"NumberType:%@",numberType);                    
 }
```

I tried all sorts of things and I've read the [ABPerson Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html) and I don't know how to get the phone number type?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have figure out how to read the localized label of the phone number

```
//get all phone numbers
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(currentPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSUInteger phoneNumberIndex;
for (phoneNumberIndex = 0; phoneNumberIndex < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumberMultiValue); phoneNumberIndex++) {

    CFStringRef labelStingRef = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex (phoneNumberMultiValue, phoneNumberIndex);

    NSString *phoneLabelLocalized = (NSString*)ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(labelStingRef);

    NSString *phoneNumber  = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumberMultiValue, phoneNumberIndex);
    //memory management
    [phoneLabelLocalized release];
    [phoneNumber release];
    CFRelease(labelStingRef);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a code snippet that creates a person, adds 2 phone contacts and then shows how to get at the label and value for the phone property:

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef multi = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
ABMultiValueIdentifier multivalueIdentifier;

ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multi, @"(555) 555-1234",
                             kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, &multivalueIdentifier);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multi, @"(555) 555-2345",
                             kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, &multivalueIdentifier);

ABRecordRef aRecord = ABPersonCreate();

CFErrorRef anError = NULL;

ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonPhoneProperty, multi, &anError);

CFRelease(multi);

multi = ABRecordCopyValue(aRecord, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(multi); i++)
{
    CFStringRef phoneNumber, phoneNumberLabel;

    phoneNumberLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multi, i);
    phoneNumber      = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i);

    NSLog(@"%@ %@", (NSString *) phoneNumberLabel, (NSString *) phoneNumber);

    CFRelease(phoneNumberLabel);
    CFRelease(phoneNumber);
}

CFRelease(aRecord);

CFRelease(multi);
```

In the code it iterates over all the multi-values and extracts the label and number as it goes, using `ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex` and `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I all ready figure out how to read the label.